# can't find translation in admin or language file in prestashop

Tags: prestashop, translation

I'm working on a prestashop that has been customized before. I'm trying to add a translation for a head title but can't translate it.
This is the line in the .tpl file :

```
<h4>{l s="saison" m="homefeatured"}</h4>
```

I tried to add myself this in the languages php files

```
$_MODULE['<{homefeatured}nop>homefeatured_62d8617d49c4cbd03664e39af6f0fe2f'] = 'SEASONS';
```

But it doesn't work and I can't find it it the admin > locations > translations > module name. I mean I see all other sentences that were here already but not this new one.

Answer (score 2):

Dummy, I found the solution.

```
<h4>{l s="saison" m="homefeatured"}</h4>
```

becomes

```
<h4>{l s='saison' mod='homefeatured'}</h4>
```